# Inserting into data into external DB using WPDB

Tags: database, wpdb

I'm trying to work with an external db in Wordpress for the first time and can't seem to get it to insert the data into the DB.
Here's what I have:

```
    <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $url = home_url();

        require_once($url.'/viper/confff.php');  //contains variable to fill in below
            $newdb = new wpdb($username, $password, $db_name, $host);
            $newdb->show_errors();
     ?>

$numrows = $newdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM chi_clients WHERE AccountNum='$acctNum'");

      if($numrows!=0)
      {
        $row =  $newdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM chi_clients WHERE AccountNum='$acctNum'",ARRAY_A);    
                $name= $row['lastName'] . ", " . $row['firstName'];
        $phone= $row['phone'];
        $phonearea = substr($phone,0,3);
        $phonemain = substr($phone,3,10);
        $phonenumber = $phonearea ."-". $phonemain;
        $email= $row['email'];

        $newdb ->insert (
                    chi_orders, array(
                        'name' => '$name',
                        'AccountNum' => '$acctNum',
                        'email' => '$email',
                        'OrderDesc' => '$orderDesc',
                        'product' => '$service',
                        'quantity' => '$quantity',
                        'notes' => '$notes',
                        'status' => 'Order Received',
                        'dateIne' => '$todayDate',
                        'dateOut' => '$newDate',
                        'advert' => '$advert',
                        'phone' => '$phonenumber'
                    )
                   );
        }


        else {
           echo'<span style="color: #000; font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px;">Incorrect Account Number!</span>';
                 }
```

I know the data is being posted to page as I have the variables echoed out to display on the page.  However it's not connecting to the Database as I'm not getting the information from the get_results SELECT statement and it's not inserting anything into database.
For my $host- I'm using 'localhost' which is what I've always used for this particular database. And I know that the username, pass, and database name are correct.

any ideas?  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `$wpdb` incorrectly Take a look at these lines:

```
$row =  $newdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM chi_clients WHERE accountNum='$acctNum'",ARRAY_A);    
$name= $row['lastName'] . ", " . $row['firstName'];
```

`$wpdb->get_results` is going to return an array of "rows". It is going to multidimensional. You are treating it like it has returned a one-dimensional array. That is, this (completely different data but illustrates the array to expect):

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  array(23) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["post_author"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["post_date"]=>
    string(19) "2013-03-26 18:37:57"
    ["post_date_gmt"]=>
    string(19) "2013-03-26 18:37:57"
    ["post_content"]=>
    string(429) "[testsc]
    ...
```

You need to loop over that result set to get to the individual rows, or do something like this:

```
$name= $row[0]['lastName'] . ", " . $row[0]['firstName'];
```

That is true *even if* the result set is one row. If you know the result set is only one row you can use `$wpdb->get_row` instead and that *will* give you a one dimensional array.

Secondly, variables do not expand inside single quotes so all of your attempts to use variables in this way-- `'name' => '$name',`-- simple won't work. You have literally set `name` to `$name`, not to the data held in the `$name` variable.

Third, the first parameter of `$wpdb ->insert` is a string representing the table name. You have used what PHP will interpret to be a constant, and almost certainly an undefined one. You need quotes around `chi_orders`.

Those are the issues that I spot. If correcting those doesn't fix it, it will move you forward quite a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the time to look this over and the explanation! I tried to give myself a crash course in WPDB today.
 This has helped a lot.
ended up that my file I'm trying to include for the connection info (confff.php) isn't working.  Since I wasn't getting any errors, I figured it was.  I made the adjustments you mentioned and entered my connection info directly into the code and it worked perfectly.  
Is this wrong? If I echo $url it gives expected result of the site url.
        $url = home_url(); require_once($url.'/viper/confff.php');

Comment: Got it!  Changed to:
define( 'SHORTINIT', true );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/viper/confff.php' );